# Angularjs: Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'carousel', required by directive 'ngTransclude', can't be found

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using **ui.bootstrap** module in my project and using carousel. The carousel working fine but it always gives error in console:

```
Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'carousel', required by directive 'ngTransclude', can't be found!
```

I've search this forum and one net and found it is a general error which people already faced.

I found one resolution but its not working in my case. Implementing the solution carousel is not working.

[Controller 'carousel', required by directive 'ngTransclude', can't be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20137900/controller-carousel-required-by-directive-ngtransclude-cant-be-found)

If someone has fixed this issue kindly share the solution. It'll be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

We were able to solve the issue by adding data-ng-non-bindable for the elements which we have `data-slide` directive

`<a data-slide="prev" href="#clients-slider" ng-non-bindable class="left carousel-control">‹</a>`